# Pouchdb update design document gives 'Invalid rev format' error

Tags: pouchdb

I want to store design documents for filtering in my PouchDB for an angular app. The PochDB will be in the browser and then (parts of it) will be replicated to the backend.

My approach is:

1. Define array with required design documents
2. When initializing the provider, update the design documents with the current definitions in the array

But when I try to do this, I get an 'Invalid rev format' error even though I use the _rev value from the existing document.

My code looks like this (where POUCH_DESIGN_DOCS is an array of design docs):

```
POUCH_DESIGN_DOCS.forEach(function (designDoc) {
    db.get(designDoc._id)
      .then(function (originalDoc) {
        console.log('found design document with given id ' + designDoc._id);
        return db.put(designDoc, designDoc._id, originalDoc._rev); // throws error
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Adding new design document with id ' + designDoc._id);
        if (err.status === 404) {
          return db.put(designDoc);
        } else {
          console.error('Error while updating design document: ', err);
        }
      });
  });
```

The get promise gets resolved as expected with an existing design document. The db.put call in the callback then throws the error.

I believe to have applied the pattern described here [Create/update a document](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_document).

<del>**Update**: I figured out that db.put may not have an ._id in the document *and* have it as argument in the call (even when tey are the same). Use `undefined` as second argument or delete the `_id` property from the document your're updating.</del>

**Update 2**: PouchDB will deprecate using `put` with additional arguments for `_id` and `_rev`. So updating the `._rev` property must be done on the document to be future proof. (See [PouchDB Issue 5154](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/5154))

Comment: If you are not too bent on doing this yourself, you can try using a library like [pouch-seed-design](https://github.com/colinskow/pouchdb-seed-design) to seed your design docs.

Comment: @HazardouS Thanks for the pointer. Even I didn't use the library, I could figure out the issue thanks to looking at the seed source code: PouchDB threw the error because I had used a mixture between providing the doc._id in the document AND as parameter in the put call (even though thei were the same. The put should be `return db.put(designDoc, undefined, originalDoc._rev);` (do not provide the doc._id outside of the document). The error message from PouchDB was somewhat misleading.

Comment: Good to know it helped! You can file an issue for a better error at PouchDB GitHub.